# bottom center some widgets in a container

Tags: dart, flutter

i want to center bottom an image and button in my container .. so i used align and set it to bottomCenter .. but its not working!

here is my container: **AFTER SOME UPDATES**

```
           return new Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              image: new DecorationImage(
                image: new AssetImage(
                    globals.uiLabels['wthimg' + (index + 1).toString()]
                    [globals.currentLang]),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2 +100),
                      child: new Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Text(
                            globals.uiLabels[
                            'wthtitle' + (index + 1).toString()]
                            [globals.currentLang],
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18.0,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: ui.FontWeight.bold),
                          ),],),),
                    new Padding(
                      padding:
                      EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, right: 10, left: 10),
                      child: new Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Text(
                            globals.uiLabels[
                            'wthdesc' + (index + 1).toString()]
                            [globals.currentLang],
                            softWrap: true,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),),],),),],),
                Align(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                          child: new Image(
                            image: AssetImage(globals.uiLabels[
                            'wthpager' +
                                (index + 1).toString()]
                            [globals.currentLang]),
                            width: 70,
                          ),
                        ),
                        new RaisedButton(
                          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius:
                              new BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                          child: new Text(
                            globals.uiLabels['skip']
                            [globals.currentLang],
                            style: new TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0),
                          ),
                          color: Color(0x0049C275),
                          elevation: 0.0,
                          onPressed: () {
                            navigationPage();
                          },),],),),
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                )],),);
```

and what i want to bottom center .. is the part inside align widget ...

tried align, stack and row .. but none worked ...

how to solve this? and make it bottom centered always...

[image: Screenshot]

Skip and the image above it .. i want them at the bottom center of the page .. but now they are at the top center

Comment: It's because of `Column`. `RaisedButton` is centered inside `Column`, but `Column` if not fit or centered inside `Container`

Comment: Use the Stack Widget and use the Align widget in it.

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky so how can i solve it?

Comment: @ibhavikmakwana tried to do that but also didn't work..

Comment: @pskink am getting that debugPaintSizeEnabled is not defined ...

Comment: @pskink just uploaded it ...

Comment: `Stack(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,)`

Comment: @pskink as they are now ..

Comment: My answer is updated. Now skip button is on bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated:

1 - for top padding use `- 100` instead of `+100`. Actually, it'll be better to use `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,` instead

2 - delete unnecessary `Column`s

3 - in last `Column` set `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,`

```
Container(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  color: Colors.black45,
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2 - 100),
            child: Text('this is the title',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: ui.FontWeight.bold),
                ),),
          Padding(
            padding:
            EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, right: 10, left: 10),
            child: Text('this is a description... ' * 3,
                  softWrap: true,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),),),],),
      Align(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                child: new Image(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/fav_list_full.png'),
                  width: 70,
                ),
              ),
              new RaisedButton(
                shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius:
                    new BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                child: new Text('skip',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0),
                ),
                color: Color(0x0049C275),
                elevation: 0.0,
                onPressed: () {
                  navigationPage();
                },),],),),
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      )],),);
```

Comment: Then try to wrap parent `Column` inside `Expanded`

Comment: still the same thing :(

Comment: still the same T____T!! its placed after the second text .. so if i have 2 lines text or 3 lines it will be at different position and not placed at the end of the page always ...

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below code:

Have created a sample:

```
child: Container(
          height: 300.0,
          width: 300.0,
          color: Colors.orange,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("One", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 48.0),),
                  Text("Two", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 48.0),),
                ],
              ),
              Align(
                child: FlutterLogo(size: 48,),
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

[image: Preview of above code]

Comment: just tried this .. and this for some reason align the children inside align at the topcenter of the page not the bottom!